# tensorflow 2.3.0: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (training procedure)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to build a hierarchical model for sequence prediction. My input is a sequence (372*49) and my output is also a sequence (372*2). The details of the model are as follows.

```
class Local(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim=128, 
                intermediate_dim=256, name='local', **kwargs):
        super(Local, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.cnn = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(7,1), padding='valid', 
                                                 input_shape=(7,7,1), activation='relu')
        self.bn = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)
        self.reshape = tf.keras.layers.Reshape((7,64))
        self.lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(200, return_sequences=False, stateful=False)
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(latent_dim, activation='relu')
        
    def call(self, batch_inputs):
        cnn_bn = self.bn(self.cnn(batch_inputs))
        cnn_drop = self.dropout(cnn_bn)
        lstm_inp = self.reshape(cnn_drop)
        lstm_out = self.lstm(lstm_inp)
        lstm_drop = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        dense_1 = self.dropout(self.dense_1(lstm_drop))
        local_out = self.dense_2(dense_1)
        return local_out

class Global(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, max_subs = 372, latent_dim = 128):
        super(Global, self).__init__()
        self.max_subs = max_subs
        self.bottom_inp_dim = latent_dim
        self.mask = tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value= -1, input_shape = (self.max_subs, self.bottom_inp_dim))
        self.rnn = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_sequences = True)
        self.dense_1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation = 'relu') #tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
        self.dense_2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu')
        self.out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid')
        
    def call(self, batch_inputs):
        x = batch_inputs
        mask = self.mask(x)
        h = self.rnn(mask)
        h_d_1 = self.dense_1(h)
        h_d_2 = self.dense_2(h_d_1)
        y = self.out(h_d_2)
        return y

class Seq(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim=128, name='seq', **kwargs):
        super(Seq, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.local_out_dim = latent_dim
        self.local = Local()
        self.pred = Global()

        
    def call(self, batch_inputs):
        batch_output = np.zeros((batch_inputs.shape[0], batch_inputs.shape[1], 2))
        for j in range(0, batch_inputs.shape[0]):
            temp = np.zeros((batch_inputs.shape[1], self.local_out_dim))
            for i in range(0,batch_inputs.shape[1]):
                inp = batch_inputs[j,i,:]
                inp = tf.reshape(inp, [1, 7, 7, 1])
                temp[i,:] = self.local(inp)
            seqinp = tf.reshape(temp, [1, batch_inputs.shape[1], self.local_out_dim])
            batch_output[j,:,:] = self.pred(seqinp)

        return batch_output
```

The **Local** layer is utilized to extract the local dependency within an input item, and the **Global** layer is utilize to learn sequential dependency between input items of a certain sequence.

```
t = np.random.random(size=(128, 372, 49))
te = np.random.random(size=(128, 372, 2))
seq = Seq()

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((t, te))
train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=128).batch(4)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
mse_loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
loss_metric = tf.keras.metrics.Mean()
vae = Seq()

for epoch in range(3):
    print('Start of epoch %d' % (epoch,))

    for (step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train)) in enumerate(train_dataset):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            pred = seq(x_batch_train)
            
            loss = mse_loss_fn (y_batch_train, pred)
        
        grads = tape.gradient(loss, seq.trainable_variables)
        optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, seq.trainable_variables))
        loss_metric(loss)
    
    if step % 100 == 0:
        print('step %s: mean loss = %s' % (step, loss_metric.result()))
```

The gradient is None when optimize loss function, and the error is:

```
---> 32         optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, seq.trainable_variables))
     33         loss_metric(loss)
     34 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py in apply_gradients(self, grads_and_vars, name, experimental_aggregate_gradients)
    511       ValueError: If none of the variables have gradients.
    512     """
--> 513     grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    514     var_list = [v for (_, v) in grads_and_vars]
    515 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py in _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
   1269   if not filtered:
   1270     raise ValueError("No gradients provided for any variable: %s." %
-> 1271                      ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))
   1272   if vars_with_empty_grads:
   1273     logging.warning(

ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['seq/local/conv2d_52/kernel:0', 'seq/local/conv2d_52/bias:0', 'seq/local/batch_normalization_52/gamma:0', 'seq/local/batch_normalization_52/beta:0', 'seq/local/lstm_97/lstm_cell_97/kernel:0', 'seq/local/lstm_97/lstm_cell_97/recurrent_kernel:0', 'seq/local/lstm_97/lstm_cell_97/bias:0', 'seq/local/dense_244/kernel:0', 'seq/local/dense_244/bias:0', 'seq/local/dense_245/kernel:0', 'seq/local/dense_245/bias:0', 'seq/global_45/lstm_98/lstm_cell_98/kernel:0', 'seq/global_45/lstm_98/lstm_cell_98/recurrent_kernel:0', 'seq/global_45/lstm_98/lstm_cell_98/bias:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_246/kernel:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_246/bias:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_247/kernel:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_247/bias:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_248/kernel:0', 'seq/global_45/dense_248/bias:0'].
```